# logic question inferences

Tags: logic

Here are two inferences A and B, one of which is valid, but the other not valid.

**Inference A**

> 1. Every human is mortal.
> 2. Socrates is human.
> 3. Therefore Socrates is mortal.

**Inference B**

> 1. Every hero likes women.
> 2. Taro likes women.
> 3. Therefore Taro is a hero.

Which one is correct, and in what sense it is correct ?

Can somebody give the hints to solve it ?

Comment: Which one seems to make sense?

Comment: "Primae sunt Barbara, ..."

Comment: I watched Taro flee in fright from a horde of Mongolians. That's no hero!

Comment: He sure does love the ladies though!

Comment: A general hint for this kind of problem is that if the inference is valid, then it must hold even if you replace all the names with other names (_e.g._ with "user77788" or with "Richard Nixon")

Comment: @Trevor: But what if someone thinks of Nixon as their hero?

Answer (score 6):

Draw a circle. Draw another circle, inside the first. Draw a point inside one of the circles and see if being inside one the circles implies being inside the other.

The difference is like between [necessary and sufficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency#Relationship_between_necessity_and_sufficiency) conditions. Being a human is sufficient to be mortal. Being mortal is necessary but not sufficient to be human. Similarly, being a lover is necessary for being a hero but not sufficient.

In probability, this fallacy is know as **Confusion of inverse**

Comment: ohh!!! i see ! Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, A -> B means that A is inside B. The set of humans is a subset of mortals. Socrates is a point inside humans. Being Socrates -> being in the ring of humen -> being inside mortals. Heroes are inside women lovers. But, being inside a big ring of human lovers does not imply that you are inside a smaller ring of heroes.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Is everyone who likes women necessarily a hero?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

**Inference B**

$\varphi(x)$ mean $x$ likes women

$Hero(p)$ means $p$ is a hero

> 1) $\forall p:Hero(p)\rightarrow \varphi(p)$
>
> 2) $\varphi(taro)$
>
> 3) $\varphi(taro)\rightarrow Hero(taro)$

So the second inference is

$(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow (Q\rightarrow P) $

Is this always true?

**Inference A**

But when we talk about socrate we have a different thing:

$\varphi(x)$ mean $x$ is mortal

$Human(p)$ means $p$ is a human

> 1) $\forall p:Human(p)\rightarrow \varphi(x)$
>
> 2) $Human(socrate)$
>
> 3) $Human(socrate)\rightarrow \varphi(socrate)$

that is very different.